# Having Problems with Hide/Show Functionality in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have some divs which are structured like this:

```
<div>
    <div><a>more Info</a></div>
    <div><a>more segments</a></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div><a>more Info</a></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div><a>more Info</a></div>
    <div><a>more segments</a></div>
</div>
.......
```

These divs are being generated dynamically. Some divs contain 2 hyperlinks (like the 1st div), some contain only one hyperlink (like the 2nd div).

1. When I click on `moreInfo link`, it has to display one div which contains some information. When I click on another link, the previously displayed div should be hidden and open appropriate div associated with that link.
2. When I click on `moresegments link`, it has to display number of segments and `all moreInfo links` should be disabled. Each segment consists of `moreInfo link`(segment consists the code just like 2nd div). After click on moreInfo link in each segment. It has to behave like in point1.
   This is my sample code http://jsfiddle.net/H5R53/16/
   In the above code, when I click on `moreInfo link` it displays one div which contains some information .Upto this it's working fine. Now my problem is, when I click on the same link again it doesn't show the Information again. And also when I click on `moresegments link` the `moreInfo links`( which are not child of moresegments link) should be disable and all opened div's( which are opened when click on moreInfo link) should be close. Anyone please help me.

Comment: Are you unable to edit the markup?

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried so far? It will make it easier to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have posted my code, please have a look where's the mistake

Comment: You should not have more than one object with the same ID. Use the class attribute.

Comment: @Dutchie432 I have changed id to class, this was updated in my post. But also no luck

Comment: I did not mean to imply that would fix your problem, but that would be step #1. What exactly is the problem you're having - seems OK to me.. http://jsfiddle.net/H5R53/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you want to hide the div #moreInfo if the user wants to open another one.

If so,

**JQUERY**

```
if ($('#moreInfo').size()==1) {
    $('#moreInfo').remove();
}
```

**YOUR JQUERY WITH THAT CONTROL ADDED**

```
$('.moreInfLink').live('click',function(){
    if ($('#moreInfo').size()==1) {
        $('#moreInfo').remove();
    }
   $(this).after("<div id='moreInfo'>sdasdad<br/>sdasdad<br/>sdasdad<br/><div id='close'>close</div></div>");
});
```

And your [Fiddle Updated!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/H5R53/17/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's working great but I also want one more requirement i.e when I ckick on moresegments div all moreInfo links(other than child of this moresegment) should be disabled.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/H5R53/19/) before I update my answer!